# git push to existing remote branch

Tags: git, git-push

How do I push changes from a local git branch to an existing non-master remote branch? If I do a "git push", it tries to push changes in all local branches to the remotes they are tracking.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To do this you use a `refspec`, as explained in the [`git push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html). For example:

```
git push origin local_branch_name:remote_branch_name
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! (what worked for me: git push origin +<local branch name>:<remote branch name> )

Comment: Be careful with that `+`, the plus sign forces the update to happen even if other commits on the remote might be thrown away. When using `git push` like this, changes are *not* automatically merged.

Comment: Ok, I will be careful. I usually pull in the changes, rebase my changes onto them, resolve any conflicts and then do a git push.

Comment: That's why I recommend *not* using the `+`. If somebody else pushes commits while you are merging, then using the `+` will throw away their commits. If you don't use `+`, you will be notified and you'll just need to pull and merge again.

Comment: how do I figure out what the remote_branch_name is?

Comment: @CharlieParker: This question and answer assumes that you already know which branch you want to push to. If you don't know which branch you want, that's a different question.

Answer (score 8):

If the branch already exists in the repository, it should just be:

> git push origin branch_name